# Locating GooglePay merchantId

Tags: google-pay

I cannot find the merchant id. I have set up a website integration in the Business Console and it has been apporoved. I can't find the merchantId though. I tried this but it `public merchant profile is not visible on that page`: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7163092?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the the top right corner of the Business Console contrary to the guides online. [image]